# How to insert multiple row result of dynamic sql to another Table?

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections, dynamic-sql

I write one dynamic SQL which the result of it is a table with 2 columns and multiple rows, I want to insert it to another table with 4 columns that 2 of them will be filled by the result of dynamic SQL, I try to use collection but don't know how to insert result to another table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_C_SM_Failure_error_Code_P2P AS

v_month          VARCHAR2(16); -- to get Month for each table
v_day            VARCHAR2(16); -- to get day for each table
v_ERRCODE        t_c_rpt_resultmsg.code%TYPE;
v_ERRMSG         t_c_rpt_resultmsg.MESSAGE%TYPE;
v_param          VARCHAR2(16);
v_sql            VARCHAR2(3000);
v_result         number;
type t_c_result is record (Err_code varchar2(2000), Err_count number);
type v_t_result is table of t_c_result index by PLS_INTEGER;
v_t1_result      v_t_result; 
BEGIN
v_sql :='0';
v_param := 'Gateway_G';
v_result := '0';
select to_char(sysdate - 1,'MM') into v_month from dual;
select to_char(sysdate - 1,'DD') into v_day from dual;

-- Get count of P2P
v_sql := '(select count(*), error_code from (
select error_code from sm_histable'||v_month||''||v_day||'@ORASMSC01 where 
orgaccount = '''||v_param||''' and destaccount = '''||v_param||''' and 
sm_status <> 1 union all
select error_code from sm_histable'||v_month||''||v_day||'@ORASMSC02 where 
orgaccount = '''||v_param||''' and destaccount = '''||v_param||''' and 
sm_status <> 1 )
group by error_code)';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql bulk collect into v_t1_result; 

--insert into t_c_rpt_result2 values (trunc(sysdate, 'DD'), v_errcount, 
v_err_code,'Failure_error_Code_P2P');


--for indx in 1 .. v_t1_result.COUNT
--loop
--dbms_output.put_line (v_t1_result (indx).Err_code);
--end loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may append the constant values of date and the error message to the subquery and run a dynamic insert. It should also work if you remove the outer parentheses of your dynamic sql since constants can be included in  `group by`. Always remember to pass values as bind variables rather than concatenating them (`v_param`). Also, specify the column names explicitly in an `INSERT` statement.

```
v_sql := '(select count(*) as cnt, error_code 
           from (
               select error_code from sm_histable'||v_month||''||v_day||'@ORASMSC01 
            where orgaccount = :x and destaccount = :x  and sm_status <> 1 
            union all
               select error_code from sm_histable'||v_month||''||v_day||'@ORASMSC02 
            where  orgaccount = :x and destaccount = :x and sm_status <> 1 )
         group by error_code)';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql bulk collect into v_t1_result using v_param; 

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into t_c_rpt_result2(err_dt,err_msg,errcount,error_code) 
                    select :dt,:msg,cnt,error_code from '|| v_sql
        USING trunc(sysdate, 'DD'),'Failure_error_Code_P2P',v_param;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at an excellent use case for FORALL. The collection you are populating needs to be done with execute immediate since you are dynamically constructing the table name. But the insert into t_c_rpt_result2 looks static to me.

```
BEGIN
   v_sql :=
         '(select count(*) as cnt, error_code 
           from (
               select error_code from sm_histable'
      || v_month
      || ''
      || v_day
      || '@ORASMSC01 
            where orgaccount = :x and destaccount = :x  and sm_status <> 1 
            union all
               select error_code from sm_histable'
      || v_month
      || ''
      || v_day
      || '@ORASMSC02 
            where  orgaccount = :x and destaccount = :x and sm_status <> 1 )
         group by error_code)';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql BULK COLLECT INTO v_t1_result USING v_param;

   FORALL indx IN 1 .. v_t1_result.COUNT
      INSERT INTO t_c_rpt_result2 (err_dt,
                                   err_msg,
                                   errcount,
                                   ERROR_CODE)
           VALUES (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'DD'),
                   'Failure_error_Code_P2P',
                   v_t1_result (indx).cnt,
                   v_t1_result (indx).ERROR_CODE);
END;
```

Find more examples of FORALL on LiveSQL [here](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:49:::NO:RP,49:P49_SEARCH:forall). Of course, even if your insert was dynamic, you can use FORALL - put the execute immediate directly "inside" the FORALL statement. But I don't think that complexity is justified here.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I change it but now it's stuck on PLS-00103-encountered the symbol exception seems there is some writing issue but I can't find it.

Comment: Majid, perhaps you could replace the code in your question with the full block or procedure that you are trying to compile and execute. Very hard to give you advice otherwise. You are also welcome to send the code directly to me at steven.feuerstein@oracle.com.